# asp.net Simple membership and oauth

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, oauth, simplemembership

I'm using Simple membership with oauth thats comes out of the box with asp.net mvc 4.  Some of my users have already registered creating a standard(not oauth) username and password but now want to use their Facebook to authenticate instead.  How can I associate their Facebook account with their existing Membership account?

Answer (score 0):

Kamran,

If you have already set up your external login (ie GOOGLE: via OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterGoogleClient() in the AuthConfig, then when you have a new user or existing user that has registered creating a standard account logs in, they can subsequently click on their account and under "add an external login" there will be all the external login providers that you have registered. This is obviously based off of the default MVC 4 internet template out of the box.